# Is it possible to programmatically change the Default.png launch image?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to programmatically change the Default.png launch image?

For example, could I replace it by an other image that fits better? My app has a tab bar and every tab has a very different screen, and I want to recover to that particular tab after a hard launch from scratch when the app got terminated in the background.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

The image Default.png is part of the bundle of your app, and you can only read this folder, you can't modify it.
There is no API to specify a different launch image.

Comment: Thanks, You just solved my problem. I was working on a old project and previous developer just changed this image and didn't set LaunchImage in "Images.xcassets". I was wondering what the hell happening at here. You "Default.png" clue solved my problem.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, you can.
There's little trick that you can do:

set up path to Launch Image in Info.plist file to something like 
../Documents/Splash.png

So, at first launch there will be no splash.
After that just copy Any file of your bundle in application Documents directory as Splash.png
And in next launch your Splash will change.

Comment: We had the problem that we are deploying a demo project which needs to switch between several launch images for different customers. By using several targets with different Info.plist files we are able to switch the launch image by selecting a different target. May be self-evident for others but before we needed to replace the Default.png for each build.

Comment: Clever idea. It won't work with 4-inch Retina which depends upon the Default Image size run full-screen.

Answer (score 4):

perhaps an idea would be for your default to be a blank "view" along with the tab bar controller at the bottom. This goes along the lines of Apples HIG.

Comment: doesn't work with iOS 4+. You never know how your app will look after launch.

Comment: When your app is launched, you always know how it will look. You're confusing launch with fast app switching, where your app is activated. There is an API for changing the image that is shown before your app is activated.